# Linear Circuits - Erroneous first order gain observation

Tags: capacitor, resistors, filter, impedance, gain

At uni, I carried out some lab observations involving a CR circuit (4V AC power source, capacitor, resistor in series, in than order) with the following parameters:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNrlBJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here are my observations in graph form:

[image: Graph detailing laboratory observations]

I attempted to measure the slope in dB/decade and recieved a value of $$g \approx +28.3dB/dec$$ but I thought values for the slope could not exceed $$g = \pm20dB/dec$$ for any first-order filters.

Any ideas why would this happen? (i.e. anything wrong with my lab setup, unforseen variables, etc.)

Comment: Could your 4V AC power source be a function generator? Most function generators have an output impedance, forming a Thevenin equivalent (Vac + series resistor).

Comment: For a linear lumped circuit, the slopes of the gain asymptotes will all be integer multiples of 20dB/decade. If you draw the graph over 4 decades, \$10^2\: \rightarrow \:10^6\:Hz\$, the asymptotes would be more apparent.

Comment: A bad reading results in app. 18dB/dec (not 28dB) and a correct reading - applying the asymptote correctly in the most left lower corner - gives 20 dB/dec, as expected.

Comment: @LvW perhaps answer so I can close this thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like 6 dB per octave to me: -

[image]

And 6 dB / octave = 20 dB / decade.

Comment: Red is simulated = expected behaviour, blue is observed = strange behaviour

Comment: Blue looks about 6 dB per decade given such things as measurement errors so what’s the problem?